# How do I force video files to be download instead of opening in the same window?

Tags: angular, cors

I have a href link to a video file which can be of any format like mp4, 3gp etc. 
When I click on that link it opens in the same tab. 
When I change target attribute to "_blank", it opens the video in a new tab. 
But when I ctrl-click that link, the file starts downloading.
How can I force download the file instead of opening it anyway? I am using angular 4 with Electron to make the desktop application so I don't want any glitch when clicking the link. How do I do it? 
Things I have tried:

1. Changing the target attribute of anchor tag.
2. Using the download attribute of anchor tag.

Nothing works for me so far.

UPDATE: 
 
Using this web app as an electron app gives CORS error. I was using an extension in the Chrome to allow CORS. How do I allow CORS in electron app? 
I tried JSONP, but API doesn't allow JSONP. I am using third party API so cannot modify server side.

Comment: As of Chrome 65, the `download` attribute has been deprecated and hence completely ignored by chrome. See here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download

Comment: This only applies to cross origin links, just to clear that out a bit. Download attribute itself isn't deprecated, that would be nuts. :)

Comment: So I guess, this CORS problem cannot be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an Electron thing, handling downloads is a bit more complicated than usual, though you also get some of the freedoms that come with making a native app.

There are helper libs built for making it simpler like electron-dl: https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-dl

There are a few others like it so search before deciding. I like this one cause it's simple and allows to ask the user for a target directory, or not, or provide both ways to choose from.

**Edit:**
More info from OP reveals it's a cors issue and cors headers can't be added to the third party service, makes it a tad more complicated but some ideas:

Create download functionality on the electron backend using [electron-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-fetch) - this should bypass cors protection.

For the web app, add a simple proxy server on the same domain you're hosting the app on, that would allow downloading files through.

Comment: The above behaviour on click was on the web app and not on electron app. Please see the updated question. Thank you.

Comment: You mean to say, I should make "fetch" requests from electron-fetch instead of "http" requests from angular? Will it resolve CORS issue?

Comment: About adding a proxy server to my domain, how will it help my electron app to download though?

Comment: Yes, fetch should work out of the box on the elctron side: No browser = no cors protection. A proxy would help the webapp version (if you plan to host one).

Comment: The API returns something like this **{ "name": "Suraj", "age": "21", "projects": { "1": "Something", "2": "something" } }** . The body of response **res**  is a "[object Object]" if res.json() is not performed. If res.json() is done then I am getting an error like **SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1** . How do I get a JSON?

Comment: Is this a response from fetch?

Comment: The API is expected to return a JSON object instead it gives errror like above.

Comment: Something weird definately bappening with the response. Looks like the json string is parsed and then the object is converted to string. Is this just from a simple fetch call or something else happening too?

Comment: `fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))`
gives error: **SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**
and if i omit `res=> res.json()` then the body of the response is something like this **[object Object]** instead of JSON object.

Comment: Weird. I get an object in console like { login: 'github', id: 9919, ...} so working as expected when I do 
`const fetch = require('electron-fetch');
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))`
You using the same electron-fetch library?

Comment: I am using correct **electron-fetch** from npm. I am getting above error in my angular application but fetch works in my node application. How can I use it in my angular 4+ app?

Comment: I am importing the module with `import fetch from 'electron-fetch'` and then `fetch( url ).then( res=> res.json() ).then( res=> { } );` . It still gives CORS in angular app.

Comment: `import fetch from 'electron-fetch'` gives error as **Cannot find module electron-fetch** although I installed the module in my angular app.

Comment: ah, it's not for browser. you need to do this on the nodejs side, using fetch on the browser side doesn't circumvent cors.

Comment: Thank you. It works in node app. I was trying to get it in Angular.
Back to the initial problem. If the file isn't on my server, how do I force download it in angular, using node if necessary? The file may be big.

Comment: Repeating my answer: There just is no way to do that in browser only. For a web app, you need a proxy (eg. nodejs server on your own domain) in between, which downloads the file and serves it to the browser. For electron, you can use electron-fetch as a proxy or electron-dl to download directly to local drive from anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. Here is the actual thing. I created a node API and used the youtube-dl module to get the URLs of youtube videos and offered them to the client in various buttons to allow them to download in different qualities. However whenever they a button is clicked the video is played on the browser itself instead of downloading. Can a proxy server on my node API help solve this problem? If yes, how do I setup it?

Comment: Yes. You could easily set up something like https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy on your api server and download vids through that.

Comment: I don't see why that couldn't be used as express middleware or in an express route too, if you use express.

Comment: I tried using **express-http-proxy** module in my express API. However, it didn't solve the problem. The video is still being played in the browser instead of downloading. The link to API code is [https://ideone.com/rbA6ik] .

Comment: Line #7 in the Ideone link.

Comment: hmm why proxying localhost? shouldn't it be something like app.use('/proxy', proxy('www.youtube.com')); ?

Comment: and are you replacing all the href:s client side to use the /proxy endpoint instead of a direct url to the 3rd party site?

Comment: from the angular front-end, I am using Http to hit API endpoint [http://localhost:8080/api/video?id=F2lN25IayH8] and this API returns the URL of video streams.

Comment: Sorry could not understand your last comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169878/discussion-between-suraj-bora-and-funkizer).

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I have found out that extracting and downloading of youtube generated links should be on the same machine. Extracting and downloading on two different machines will never work because of IP and cookies issue.
However, I have found a hack to this problem. Just **append** `'&title='~${actual_title_of_file}` at the end of youtube-dl generated links. However, some links will have to be downloaded manually.
Ref: [youtube-dl issue #5960](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5960/)

Comment: FYI, the question didn't say anything at all about it being related to YouTube. If it had, you might have been given answers earlier that were more relevant to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I told all the queries in the comments of the @funkizer 's answer. But I am opening this question for general video link instead of youtube by youtube-dl.